# Laravel Blade: How to get the parent URL

Tags: laravel, url-routing, laravel-blade

Is there a way to retrieve the parent URL of the current URL in blade? For example, if I am at `/users/1` I want to get to `/users`. E.g.:

```
<a href="{{ parent() }}">Back</a>
```

I want it to be reusable for all resources, so I don't want `url('/users')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
@php $url = url()->current(); @endphp

<a href="{{ substr($url,0,strrpos($url,'/')) }}">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always

> < something >/number

you can use `request()->segment(1);`

If this is not the case you can write a reusable helper

```
public function removeLastSegment(string $url): string
{
    $stringParts = explode('/', $url);
    array_pop($stringParts); // remove last element
    return implode('/', $stringParts);
}
```

Comment: I'm in blade, I don't have access to `$request`.

Comment: you do, just need to use the helper. I changed the answer

Comment: `request()->segment(1)` returns just the first segment, is there a way to get the complete URL before the second segment?

Comment: concatenate with `getHost()`?

Comment: Ok, and if I have multiple segments to retrieve, for exemple `/admin/users/1`, is there a better way than doing several times `request()->segment(...)`?

Comment: No, I have to append both `/admin` and `/users` to `getHost()`.